# IIS .Net HttpModule Advanced Logging Fields

Tags: .net, iis, logging, iis-7, httpmodule

I'm trying to find a way to log the regex that was used to the match a route from MVC3 (i.e. `/api/person/{personid}/address/{addressid}`)

I've found that you can use `HttpResponse.AppendToLog` in order to append something onto the **cs-uri-query** in the IIS logs, but this is pretty hacky and makes processing the logs a pita.This has led me to `HttpModules` and IIS7 Advanced logging.

My current understanding is that I can make fields available to Advanced Logging from an `HttpModule`. So I should be able to look up the regex used by the Route object in the `HttpContext` and expose that as a field that Advanced Logging can consume and log.

**My issue is that I'm having issues figuring out exactly how to expose data as a field in a custom `HttpModule` that Advanced Logging can consume.**

Do I need to have an event handler for `LogRequest`? If I do that what am I supposed to do in the event handler to make it consumable for Advanced Logging?

Any pointers, code samples and/or links to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

As an aside if you know of any documentation explaining/listing the available 'published' fields from default modules installed in IIS7 I'd appreciate a link.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the way that I end up dealing with this is to create a `HttpModule` that will pull the route pattern from the `HttpContext` and put into the server variables as `URL_PATTERN`.

Once its in `server_variables` IIS7 Advanced Logging can get ahold of it and save it. If the current request doesn't have a route it'll just use the normal local portion of the url (so it'll match **cs-uri-stem** in the logs).

**Now sql / log parser the query:**

```
select url_pattern,count(url_pattern) from (yourlogs) where timestamp between (start/end) group by url_pattern order by count(url_pattern) desc
```

will give me back the number of hits for each endpoint in my app.

This could obviously be done in fubu a behaviour, but we've got a bunch of classic asp and MVC3 running around (*i know I know...*) and this will handle all of them.

Also you can apparently 'publish' a field from a module using `RaiseTraceEvent` that IIS7 Advanced Logging can then get ahold of, but it was giving me fits trying to figure it out so I just went with what I have.

I've posted this question all over the place referencing fubu and MVC3 and I have gotten little to no interest, which really suprised me. How do people poke about in their logs for info if you can't easily determine the routes being used.

https://gist.github.com/2854760

I'll just leave this here....
There are still several unanwsered parts to this so I'll leave this post, but not mark it an anwser.